# How to avoid search results through website like https://search-7.com/ in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, search

I am finding it difficult to search through google normally.

[1] When I search anything in google home page -

```
  https://www.google.co.in/
```

[2] It shows the search answers in -

```
  https://search-7.com/search.php?q=stackoverflow
```

Instead of through this -

```
  https://www.google.com/search
```

I am unable to figure it out even via the chrome settings. I guess it is called as proxy website. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I have to tell you that yesterday, I suffered from it as well. Now I can tell you that it is actually a kind of virus. It hijacks your browsers and when you search with Google it issues a redirect to a URL beginning with search-7.com . You should find out when the symptom occured first time, and think about what you downloaded and installed on that day. Having finished these, you need to simply unloaded these suspicious software or use an antivirus software to help you clean the virus away. Hope I can help you.